# How to use "related" in odoo

Tags: odoo

I have class:

```
    class test(models.Models):
       _name = "student"
       .....
       gender = fields.Selection([
            ('m', 'Male'),
            ('f', 'Female'),
            ('o', 'Other')
```

and I have class another one:

```
class get_Value(models.Models):
     _name = "school"

     student_id = fields.Many2one("module.test", string="Student")
     gender = fields.Char(string="Gender", related="student_id.gender")
```

And odoo false.

Comment: Did you have any issues? Refer to [related fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/orm.html#related-fields) to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

your code should look like this:

Student:

```
class Student(models.Models):
    _name = "modulename.student"
    
    gender = fields.Selection([
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
        ('o', 'Other')
    ])
```

School:

```
class School(models.Models):
     _name = "modulename.school"

     student_id = fields.Many2one("modulename.student", string="Student")
     gender = fields.Selection(string="Gender", related="student_id.gender")
```

1. It is better to have class names that make sense. (e.g. Student for your student class) Also it is recommended to namespace your classes with your modulename (e.g. `modulename.modelname`)
2. Your Many2one relation needs to point to the _name field of the other class.
3. You are relating to a field of a different type.

You can find more information here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/backend.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set another type of field for related fields, it should be the same, in this case `selection`.

```
 gender = fields.Selection(related="student_id.gender")
```

Comment: I misspelled "Selection". But line code  gender = fields.selection(, related="student_id.gender") not run.